# Why did Lee lie to Lady Jin Ho-gyeong?

Tags: alchemy-of-souls

Initially, when Herb Master Lee helped heal

> Naksu

he lied to Jin Ho-gyeong, telling her that her daughter's soul was completely gone and that only Naksu's soul could be recovered, while asking her whether he should save Naksu's life or let them both die.

Why did he do this? Presumably, if anything, this would have made Ho-gyeong *less* likely to want to save Naksu, so one presumes he had a reason.